# Why are these timings for Pick so different?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, packed-arrays

I construct two lists, to be used in `Pick` as the second argument. The first one is a -1, 1 list and the second one is identical, but with -1 replaced with 0.

```
n=5*10^6;
a= RandomChoice[{-1,1}, {n}];
b=Unitize[1+a];
```

Because of the identical structure of both lists, I would have expected that the following timings would give about the same result.

```
Pick[Range[n], a, 1];// RepeatedTiming
Pick[Range[n],10 a, 10];// RepeatedTiming
Pick[Range[n], b, 1];// RepeatedTiming
Pick[Range[n], 10b, 10];// RepeatedTiming

(*
{0.38,Null}
{0.100,Null}
{0.069,Null}
{0.0780,Null}
*)
```

They are pretty different. Looking for 1 in the -1, 1 list is almost four times slower than looking for 10 in the corresponding -10, 10 list.

In the following two commands, the arguments of `Pick` are identical. Nevertheless, there is a non neglectable difference in the timing:

```
Pick[Range[n], a+1, 2]; // RepeatedTiming
Pick[Range[n], 2b, 2]; // RepeatedTiming

(*
{0.102,Null}
{0.0773,Null}
*)
```

What is the reason for these timings being so different?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is explained by array packing:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {a, b}
(* {False, True} *)
```

Since version 8 (I think), `Pick` is optimized for packed arrays and runs much faster with them.  `Range[n]` is packed as well.

My timings for your inputs are almost identical to what you show, so I won't repeat them.  Here's my timings with a packed version of `a`:

```
In[9]:= a2 = Developer`ToPackedArray[a];

In[10]:= Pick[Range[n], a2, 1]; // RepeatedTiming
Pick[Range[n], 10 a2, 10]; // RepeatedTiming

Out[10]= {0.077, Null}

Out[11]= {0.086, Null}
```

---

**But why is `Pick` fast with `10 a` if `a` is not packed?**  This was a surprise to me.  It turns out that this multiplication automatically packs the array.  Or rather:

**Arithmetic operations such as `Times` and `Plus` appear to return a packed result when appropriate, even if the input was not packed.**

```
In[13]:= Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {a, 10 a}    
Out[13]= {False, True}
```

Creating a new packed array accounts for about 0.02 seconds of the timing, the rest is `Pick`:

```
In[14]:= Developer`ToPackedArray[a]; // RepeatedTiming    
Out[14]= {0.019, Null}
```

I verified that this auto packing happens at least as far back as version 9.  I am curious when it was introduced.  Is the feature as old as packed arrays themselves?  Can someone test this please?

Comment: With *Mathematica* 5.2 ``n = 5*10^6;
a = Developer`FromPackedArray@Table[Random[Real, {-1, 1}], {n}]; 
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {a, 10 a}`` returns `{False, True}`. So this optimization dates back at least to version 5.2.

Comment: A perfect answer, thanks!